# How to represent array of tuples in minizinc?

Tags: arrays, iterable, minizinc

In minizinc, you can represent an array as such:

```
var array[size] of type: [x|x in iterable].
```

I have an iterable from which I am extracting tuples, as follows:

```
var array[size,1..2] of type: [x1,x2|x1,x2 in iterable where x1>x2].
```

I am running into syntax errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: there are no tuples in Minizinc.
The long answer is that if you want to do further analysis on x1 and x2 as outlined above. You can do:

```
array[size] of var int:v1= [x1|x1,x2 in iterable where x1>x2].
array[size] of var int:v2= [x2|x1,x2 in iterable where x1>x2].
```

Now you have the two variables v1 and v2 at your disposal.

Comment: There are tuples since `2.7.x` https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.6/en/tuple_and_record_types.html